# Serializing a Inner Class instance

Tags: java, serialization, inner-classes

Is it possible to serialize a non Static Inner class?

If yes can you provide a good example.

I googled through few blogs and sites non of answer convinced me.

**EDIT:**
 How about the  inner class having final staic variable.

Comment: Why not `implement Serializable` on the inner class?

Comment: per [hawaii.five-0](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1331415/hawaii-five-0)'s answer drawing from official source. serializing inner class (both local and annonymous) is strongly *strongly* discouraged because different implementation of javac (compilers: Sun,IBM, android dalvik) will behave differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Inner class contains an implicit reference to the outer class, so for
>   an inner class to be serializable its outer class must be as well.

**Exactly from docs:**

> Serialization of inner classes (i.e., nested classes that are not
>   static member classes), including local and anonymous classes, is
>   strongly discouraged for several reasons. Because inner classes
>   declared in non-static contexts contain implicit non-transient
>   references to enclosing class instances, serializing such an inner
>   class instance will result in serialization of its associated outer
>   class instance as well. Synthetic fields generated by javac (or other
>   JavaTM compilers) to implement inner classes are implementation
>   dependent and may vary between compilers; differences in such fields
>   can disrupt compatibility as well as result in conflicting default
>   serialVersionUID values. The names assigned to local and anonymous
>   inner classes are also implementation dependent and may differ between
>   compilers. Since inner classes cannot declare static members other
>   than compile-time constant fields, they cannot use the
>   serialPersistentFields mechanism to designate serializable fields.
>   Finally, because inner classes associated with outer instances do not
>   have zero-argument constructors (constructors of such inner classes
>   implicitly accept the enclosing instance as a prepended parameter),
>   they cannot implement Externalizable. None of the issues listed above,
>   however, apply to static member classes.

So

> Because inner classes declared in non-static contexts contain implicit
>   non-transient references to enclosing class instances, serializing
>   such an inner class instance will result in serialization of its
>   associated outer class instance as well.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html)

Comment: How about the inner class having final staic variable?

Comment: check [this](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/Java/archives/0511/Callahan/index.html) - section `Handling Static Variables`.