# Serialization of inner class (Java)

Tags: java

I have class Solution, that contains inner class A, class B, class C.
Class B extends class A, class C extends class B.

I want class C to be Serializable, so I implements Serializable in class C and in class Solution (class C is inner class of class Solution).

Because class C extends class B and class B extends class A, I create a no-arg constructor in class B and class A (I don't want them implements Serializable).

So the following code:

```
public class Solution implements Serializable {
    public class A {
      String name = "A";
      public A(String name) {
        this.name += name;
      }
      public A() {}
    }
    
    public class B extends A {
      String name = "B";
      public B(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.name += name;
      }
      public B() {}
    }

    public class C extends B implements Serializable {
       String name;
       public C(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.name = name;
       }
    }
}
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Solution.C c = new Solution().new C("C");
    System.out.println(c.name);

    System.out.println("serialization");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\1.txt"));
    oos.writeObject(c);
    oos.close();

    System.out.println("deserialization");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\1.txt"));
    Solution.C c1 = (Solution.C) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    System.out.println(c1.name);
  }
}
```

throws the following exception:

```
C
serialization
deserialization
Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: Test3.Solution$C; no valid constructor
```

Comment: Inner classes have an implicit constructor argument, the outer class instance. This doesn’t work with Serialization the way you tried. Since you’re not using the outer instance, you could convert them to nested classes (declare `public static class …`).

Comment: @Holger Post answer.

Comment: @Holger, so there is no way to make this code work without converting in nested class?

Comment: Your code seems to be just an example. I don’t know why these classes are inner classes (they’re not using the outer instance). If the serialization worked, it hadn’t restored the fields of the non-serializable classes, including the outer instance reference, so these objects would be broken.

Comment: I'm running your code through a debugger right now. It's looking for a constructor for 2 fields: `name`, as well as an instance of the containing class `Solution`. Now I'll move on to try fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens in your case is that the deserialization code is eventually going to construct an instance of `ObjectStreamClass` for your class `Solution.C`. In the constructor of this class, it tries to find a constructor of the class to deserialize that is suitable. In your case, it will call `ReflectionFactory#newConstructorForSerialization`. Here's what the documentation of this method says:

> Returns a constructor that allocates an instance of cl and that then initializes the instance by calling the no-arg constructor of its first non-serializable superclass. This is specified in the Serialization Specification, section 3.1, in step 11 of the deserialization process. If cl is not serializable, returns cl's no-arg constructor. If no accessible constructor is found, or if the class hierarchy is somehow malformed (e.g., a serializable class has no superclass), null is returned.

Your first non-serializable superclass is B, however B has no no-arg constructor because all its constructors have a synthetic parameter of type `Solution`. Thus, no constructor is found and deserialization fails. When you make `B` and `A` serializable, it works because `newConstructorForSerialization` will go up to `Object` (see loop below) and use its no-arg constructor.

```
public final Constructor<?> newConstructorForSerialization(Class<?> cl) {
    Class<?> initCl = cl;
    while (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(initCl)) {
        Class<?> prev = initCl;
        if ((initCl = initCl.getSuperclass()) == null ||
            (!disableSerialConstructorChecks && !superHasAccessibleConstructor(prev))) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    Constructor<?> constructorToCall;
    try {
        constructorToCall = initCl.getDeclaredConstructor();
        int mods = constructorToCall.getModifiers();
        if ((mods & Modifier.PRIVATE) != 0 ||
                ((mods & (Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.PROTECTED)) == 0 &&
                        !packageEquals(cl, initCl))) {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        return null;
    }
    return generateConstructor(cl, constructorToCall);
}
```

Can you just avoid doing this altogether? Reading the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797754/serializing-a-inner-class-instance), it seems strongly discouraged to serialized inner instances like you're doing now (full explanation in the link). You're giving yourself a hard time trying to do this, but at least now we know why this was failing.

Comment: I understand that my inner instance contains a reference to the outer instance of Solution, but if I I remove from class C "extends B" and line "super(name)" the serialization and deserialization goes well. So I thought that problem was in inheritance, not in inner-outer classes.

Comment: Indeed, just tried it. Interesting

Comment: Also, it's probably not a good idea to declare a field with the same name and type in all subclasses....

Comment: When you set the superclass as serializable, it works. I'm digging deeper into the code to see exactly why, but essentially you're making your life very hard by adding all these constraints together :D

Comment: I found the root cause and edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Default constructor for parent classes are not required. Making class A as serializable it will work. You may also remove the serialization from class C.

```
public class Solution implements Serializable {
public class A implements Serializable{
  String name = "A";
  public A(String name) {
    this.name += name;
  }
  public A() {}
}

public class B extends A {
  String name = "B";
  public B(String name) {
    super(name);
    this.name += name;
  }
  public B() {}
}

public class C extends B {
   String name;
   public C(String name) {
    super(name);
    this.name = name;
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, it will work, but I try to make only class C to be Serializable.
If we delete class Solution (class A, B, C no more inner classes) then my code will work.
But with class Solution i got an exception and I can't understand why.